# How do I show an automatically hidden div based on radio input using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a yes/no radio group that I want to use to show a div when *no* is checked. The div needs to be hidden when the page loads, unless *no* is already checked.

It works when changing from yes to no but the div is visible when the page loads. I think I need to initially test if the *euResidentNo* input is checked but I can't work out how to do that. I'm also unsure if this is the best way to achieve what I need. Thanks.

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/paulyabsley/2Uj9F/5/

### HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="euResident" id="euResidentYes" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" name="euResident" id="euResidentNo" value="No" />

<div id="div">
    ...
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=euResident]").change(function(){
        if($("#euResidentNo").prop("checked"))
        {
            $("#div").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#div").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger the `change` handler on page load

```
$('input[name=euResident]').change();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Uj9F/19/)

Also, you can simplify the code to:

```
$("input[name=euResident]").change(function(){
    $('#div').toggle( $('#euResidentNo').is(':checked') );
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `.change()` to the end of your handler, this invokes it immediately:

```
$("input[name=euResident]").change(function(){
    if($("#euResidentNo").prop("checked"))
    {
        $("#div").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#div").hide();
    }
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function switchVar() {
    if($("#euResidentNo").prop("checked"))
        $("#div").show();
    else
        $("#div").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    switchVar();
    $("input[name=euResident]").change(switchVar);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Uj9F/16/)

This will check whether or not no is checked, and if it is will show the div.

Answer (score 0):

[**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('input[name=euResident]').trigger('change');
```